# Laravel 5.2 JSON response to request with wrong api_token

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

I use auth:api middleware in controller (Laravel 5.2).

```
class RestfulController extends Controller
    {

        public function __construct() {
            $this->middleware(['api', 'auth:api'], ['except' => ['login'] ]);
        }

    }
```

**routes:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::get('/login', ['uses' => 'RestfulController@login', 'as'=>'login']);
    Route::get('/list', ['uses' => 'RestfulController@list', 'as'=>'list']);
});
```

If request doesn't contain or contains invalid api_token framework redirects to login page. Instead I would like to return JSON response with error. How it can be implemented?

Comment: Hello can you show your routes file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php handle method,it will response json

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax() || $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            $response = [
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'This is error message'
            ];
            return Response::json($response);
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check `api` and `auth:api` middleware group and look for witch one is doing it. If it's inside a vendor package, you'll need to extend it and make your changes.

Comment: Please give an example for better undestading