# Laravel API: display error message for invalid token?

Tags: laravel, api

I set up a simple api authentication with a hashed token as explained in the laravel [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/api-authentication)

```
// app/Http/Controllers/Api/Blog/PostController.php

class PostController extends Controller
{
  
   ...

    public function show($post)
    {   
        if (!$post = Post::select('title', 'slug', 'content')->find($post)) {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Ressource not found.'
            ], 404);
        }   

        return response()->json($post);
    }

    ...   

}

   


// routes/api.php

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::apiResource('posts', PostController::class);
});
```

Now, in Postman if I send a request along with a valid token:

```
https://example.com/myapp/public/api/posts/5?api_token=tLcCDe6jCiYhuhUtVWwmnCbddSY7w9m4GIp6UXahyojW5O2YXPTpc4A7XRYV
```

I get the expected data in JSON format.

Now if I modify the token on purpose in order to simulate an invalid token, the request is redirected to the login page and I get the HTML code of the page in Postman with a 200 OK status.
But what I want is to display a 401 error message in JSON instead.
How can I do that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49358484/laravel-api-authentication-redirects-to-login-instead-of-simple-401-page/50740220

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.2 JSON response to request with wrong api\_token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36529429/laravel-5-2-json-response-to-request-with-wrong-api-token)

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58115803/is-there-any-way-to-change-response-of-authapi-a-laravel-api-token

Comment: add `Content-Type` = `application/json` header in request.